# Error when registeringArray ([0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'name' in 'field list')

Tags: php

I created all the files in my database, all right, but I get this error when registering a user. I searched and found that because the name column is a varchar field, the insertion requires single quotation marks because the value to be passed is the string.

"INSERT INTO videos SET id_aula = {$ id_aula}, name = '{$ name}'"
He just added the single quotes to send the name value as a string. but I can not identify anyway, can someone please help me?

Code

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

// pega os dados do formuário
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : null;

// validação (bem simples, só pra evitar dados vazios)
if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($senha))
{
    echo "Volte e preencha todos os campos";
    exit;
}

// insere no banco
$PDO = db_connect();
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, email, senha) VALUES(:name, :email, :senha)";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha);

if ($stmt->execute())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else
{
    echo "Erro ao cadastrar";
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Check your table structure.

Comment: Have you tried passing the `data_type` argument to `bindParam`? =>  `$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, \PDO::PARAM_STR);`
I'm not sure, because I don't know how the POST-Array looks like...

Comment: Not sure about the first INSERT you give, but there shouldn't be spaces in the fields - `{$ name}` -> `{$name}`

Comment: `column is a varchar field, the insertion requires single quotation marks because the value to be passed is the string`  This is 100% wrong, when using prepared statements.

Comment: @NigelRen where?

Comment: Have you tried running the query (with some sample values instead of placeholders ) in something like PHPmyAdmin.  This will let you test the SQL outside of PHP, that way you can better tell which is wrong, the PHP or the SQL.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Actually I'm a beginner, I have no idea how to do this :(

Comment: @NigelRen I did not understand :(